# Best Tool to collect Java process statistics and Explanation of JMAP

Tags: java, monitoring, jmap

I am looking at collecting more detailed java statistics (in plain text format) i.e. statistics that the jstat command emits - like garbage collection data etc. Can anyone please suggest me the best tool to collect the java process statistics like jmap.

### EDIT

Google gives me advise to use `jmap` with `-histo:live` option, but I am not able to understand what information it actually provides. The command I am using is

```
jmap -histo:live $PID
```

Output:

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:         13767        1453320  <constMethodKlass>
   2:         13767        1105416  <methodKlass>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also take a look at [this](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/jmx/) which is free and is part of the Java API. There are some [tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jmx/overview/index.html) that explain how to use this technology. Hope this helps ...

~Bolt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could investigate integrating [Shadowtail](http://shadowtail.sourceforge.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id=16&Itemid=111) with your application.